# How to receive an Australian tourist visa after getting denied once?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, australia, iranian-citizens

I'm an Iranian citizen, resident in Iran. My sister has lived in Australia for 5 years and is an Australian citizen. My family applied for a tourist visa (subclass 600) to attend her wedding ceremony and visit Australia.

My family were all refused a visa on suspicion that they may not come back to Iran. They are frequent tourists and have traveled many countries (Schengen, Brazil, South Africa, Russia, India, Philippines, etc) and they never overstayed on those trips. They provided financial capacity, employment commitment, wedding invitation and other necessary documents. Their request was rejected based on suspicion of possible overstay and possibly not coming back to Iran at all.

I want to know, is there anything that my sister or her fiance can do to revise this decision? For example, can my sister take the responsibility of their promised stay and take responsibility to make them go back to Iran? Is it possible for him in Iran to produce a financial document promising to coming back to Iran? Like placing their home's ownership document in Australia's embassy in Iran for assurance of their return?

The refusal Letter goes like below. I've edited out the personal information:

> I note that you are a ... years old male residing in Iran. I note that
>   you wish to travel to Australia to attend the wedding ceremony of your
>   relative (your sisters sister in law) for a period of 3 months.
>
> I note that you have stated on your application form that you are the
>   manager at ..... Co. since ..... and you have provided copy of your
>   employment certificate and social security premium as evidence. I have
>   given weight to this fact at the time of assessment.
>
> I note that you have provided your evidence of funds (your bank
>   statement and house ownership). However, I place limited weight on
>   these financial assets as inducement to return to Iran as these assets
>   are transferable and could be potentially withdrawn, sold and/ or
>   accessed from within Australia.
>
> I note that you have previous international travel history. I have
>   given weight to this fact at the time of assessment of your
>   application. However, there are other factors and findings outweighing
>   these compliant overseas travels when deciding your application.
>
> I note that you travelling with your wife and dependent child and will
>   therefore have no immediate family (namely your spouse or dependent
>   children) remaining in Iran to act as incentive for your return to
>   Iran and I also considered you have no close family ties in Australia.
>
> I have carefully considered all affidavits you have provided. However
>   by taking into account your circumstances in Iran and your proposed
>   visit to Australia and weighed these against the risks of you
>   remaining in Australia. I have determined that based on your personal
>   circumstances I am not satisfied that your intention only to visit
>   Australia is genuine and I am not satisfied that you will not use the
>   Tourist visa, if granted, for other purposes or as a means to seek to
>   remain in Australia.
>
> Therefore, I am not satisfied that you have met the legal requirements
>   in clause 600.211 of Schedule 2 of the Regulations.

Comment: Can you please upload a scan of the Refusal Letter and Decision Record (with your personal details blacked out)?  This will provide with further details on the exact reason(s) why the visas were refused.

Comment: @k2moo4 I've added the detail section of refusal letter in question.

Comment: There a reason we ask for a scan/photo. We can't be sure you haven't left anything out, or made some very unfortunate typo in your attempt to quote the letter.

Comment: I wouldn't travel so far to a sister's sister in law's wedding, let alone bring the family. Different families are different, but I guess they suspect the wedding is an excuse to relocate the family.

Comment: I'm afraid that extract is not sufficient, as different rules apply depending on whether you are applying under the Sponsored Family stream or the Tourist stream.

Comment: On the face of it the decision is unfair.

Comment: I know next to nothing about visas. But the quoted letter seems to have taken into account everything you mentioned. So as the entry clearance officer knew all the information, and decided not to grant the visa, I suspect there's nothing you can do.

Comment: @k2moo4: sorry, I don't have access to refusal document right now, I copy/paste the above text from exact document so it does not contain any error or typo. we all applied under Tourist stream. I contacted Australian embassy in Tehran and they suggest the refused ones try applying under Sponsored Family but it has 2 problem; 1. they must be a close relative (they are not relative by definition of law), and 2. it will take about 2 month for any answer on this visa so basically wedding is passed.

Comment: 3 months?  How long are persian weddings???  Seriously that's what I noticed, is it makes the employment seem non-legitimate, what real job can spare someone for 3 months? What about wife's job, school for the kids etc.?   Also 3 months of staying in Australia is not cheap, especially for a whole family.  That long stay seems fishy.  Was your return ticket booked?

Comment: @harper: in online application for tourist visa for Australia, the minimum time you can request is a 3 month, it's a drop-down and u can select between up to 3 month, up to 6 month and up to 1 year. Then they process your visa and give visa validation time based on your situation (less or more than your request). for example, my parents requested up to 1 year visa, but they granted them a 3 year multi entry visa.

Comment: @AbtinL  oh.  [Neeeevermind!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZLeaSWY37I)

Comment: @Abtin L You must state your duration of stay when you apply your visa which can be less than 3 months. For Example, you'll be traveling to Australia from 10-15 Jan 2018, totaling 6 days. By the way, You're at risk being denied visa if you wish to travel to Australia for 3 months because no one can take leave from work just so long like that, so the embassy may see that you're not have enough incentives to come back to Iran when you're completed your journey in Australia because you really don't need your job.

Comment: @BeethovenTop As I mentioned earlier in comments, you can't request a visa for less than 3 month. it's a drop-down menu that you must specified your requested time of visa and the minimum time is 3 month for tourist visa.

Comment: There must be an alternative, perhaps you could report to he cop shop every fortnight, as a part of your visit.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly re-apply for an Australian visit visa, but you will have to overcome the conclusion reached in your previous application. The wedding mentioned in your last application has long since passed, your relationship to the family was questioned, as was how long you wanted to be there.

Your refusal, under [600.211 Schedule 2 of the Regulation](http://www5.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/cth/num_reg/mar20131n32o2013399/sch2.html), basically says you were not believed to be a genuine visitor, and there was a likelihood that you might overstay or otherwise breach visa conditions.

However, there were strong points in your favor: employment, home ownership, funds, travel history, so perhaps you mistakenly indicated 3 months, rather than what might be considered reasonable for such an event, e.g, 7-10 days.

In any future application, you might consider [why you wish to visit](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1) and present a very strong premise (in light of the refusal on record) and whether [migration might be an option](https://www.australia.gov.au/information-and-services/immigration-and-visas/migration-to-australia).